# How to determine if 2 components are on the same frame? (SWING)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent

I could go on and iterate over their parents using getParent() on each until i get to a shared parent or null, but this looks like a bad solution, is there a better approach?

Basiclly my use case is in a FocusListener, on focusLost() i want to know if i am losing focus to something thats outside my frame...

Comment: Why iterate? Can't you compare the parent of your two components? Can they be nested on several levels?

Comment: If they were not you could use `getParent()`, but they are on different level I think StanislavL's answer should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the result of:

```
SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(comp1).equals(SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(comp2))
```

**OR**

```
SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(comp1).equals(SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(comp2))
```

**OR**

```
SwingUtilities.getRoot(comp1).equals(SwingUtilities.getRoot(comp2))
```

Answer (score 3):

JComponent has method

```
/**
 * Returns the top-level ancestor of this component (either the
 * containing <code>Window</code> or <code>Applet</code>),
 * or <code>null</code> if this component has not
 * been added to any container.
 *
 * @return the top-level <code>Container</code> that this component is in,
 *          or <code>null</code> if not in any container
 */
public Container getTopLevelAncestor()
```

so you can compare the Containers of both components